# Suppose $\mu$ and $\nu$ are finite positive measures on a measuable space

Tags: measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

The problem is as follow:

Suppose $\mu$ and $\nu$ are finite positive measures on a measuable space (X, M). Show there is $f\in L^1(X,\mu)$ so that $\int f \ d\mu=\int (1-f) \ d\nu$.

I know that $f\in L^1(X,\mu)$ means $\int f d \mu < \infty $, but not sure how to continue here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: try constant functions! 
Let $0<a,b<\infty$ be the total measure of $X$ w.r.t. $\mu, \nu$. Then what is the integral of the constant $c$ function w.r.t. $\mu, \nu$?

Comment: So we have ca=b-cb, then we only need to let the constant function f=c=b/(a+b), that would be the answer?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Congratulations! (So I guess that means my answer deserves an upvote and your acceptance?)

Comment: Yes, thank you so much!!!

Comment: You are welcome. The problem was nice. Not to be greedy, but no upvote? (Click on the triangle above the number zero...)

Comment: I did upvote, it says it’s recorded but doesn’t change the publicly display?

Comment: Ah, yes. You probably have to gain more reputation points before your votes are displayed. No worries, I forgot about that rule.